# Error converting data type nvarchar to float in select union

Tags: sql-server

I have four tables in SQl Server. When I select from each of them everything is fine and the results are shown in the grid.

When I do a select with a union of the four tables I receive the following error:
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Any ideas?

Comment: Clearly your tables have different definitions and so when some of the values are implicitly converted (per [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) the conversion fails.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. All the columns in all tables are float and nvarchar(255).

Comment: Yes, but clearly you are trying to `UNION (ALL)` and where there is at least one instance where a column is an `nvarchar` in one table, and a `float` in another.

Comment: Youa re right! Problem solved!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.